# Adding images to dom, then wait for them to load

Tags: jquery, dom

This is a simple question..

I get a playlist, and then I want to load each image into the dom * there are videos to.

So after all the media has finished loading, I want to be able to call some function.

But in the case below the part `console.log("loaded + images")` gets called immediately because the DOM was loaded, and after that the images gets added. How would I do it so that it will tell me when all those images were loaded ?

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
            _.each(playlist, function(el) {
                $(".hidden").append("<img src='"+ el.path +"''>")
            });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).ready(function() {
            console.log("loaded + images")
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `load` method to dynamically created images, so that when the image has finished loading, you can catch this.

e.g.

```
var img = $('<img />', { attr: { src: el.path }}).load(function(){
    // your code here
}));
$(".hidden").append(img);
```

With this, you can have a global count which checks against the number of images that you have. When the global count of images loaded matches the total number of images, then you can call your `console.log("loaded + images");` code.

I have put together a little [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/cDTSp/) so you can see it in action.